# Generate batch QR Codes with node and npm qrcode package

Tags: node.js, bash, npm, batch-processing, qr-code

How can I write a script to convert names in a CSV file into QRCODES.

I have a CSV file called names.csv with 5000 names.
I have also installed [qrcode](https://www.npmjs.com/package/qrcode) package
In the folder where the csv file is I ran from bash

```
qrcode "John Doe" john_doe.png
```

That created a qrcode for John Doe.

Now I need to create 5000 more qrcodes from the CSV. I have definately no Idea, how to go about that.

I also tried running

```
qrcode names.csv names.png
```

But That created just 1 qrcode image.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Another version - limits the use of command substitution:

```
#!/bin/bash

set -e

while IFS= read -r name; do
  file=${name/ /_}.png
  qrcode "$name" "$file"
done < names.csv
```

Assumes that the file `names.csv` only has one "field" - each full line is a name. Also, using `set -e` means that the script exits if any `qrcode` invocation fails.

Answer (score 2):

Something like this?

```
#!/bin/bash

IFS=$'\n'; 
for name in $(cat names.csv); do 
  qrcode "$name" $(echo $name | tr ' ' '_').png;
done
```

**IFS=$'\n'** - takes new line as delimiter. Since you will have white spaces in lines, you want to set is as new line to properly run it through the loop.

**tr ' ' '_'** - this actually sets the output for the image name. We replace the space between the First name and the Last name into a underscore **_**